# xml.value - problem with dynamic path containting slash character

Tags: xml, t-sql

I've got a problem with reaching values in xml by xml.value when I want to use dynamic path with slash character in it. In my app from outer service I am receiving two types of XML's, but only difference is two "root" nodes, the rest of XML is identical.

First type of XML:

```
<CreditInquiryResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<creditReport>
    <reportHeader>  
        <userId>USERNAME1</userId>
        -- some other nodes
    </reportHeader>
    -- some other nodes
</creditReport>
```

Second type:

```
<BIKReportResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ReportObject>
    <reportHeader>  
        <userId>USERNAME1</userId>
        -- some other nodes
    </reportHeader>
    -- some other nodes  
    </reportHeader>
</ReportObject>
```

When I am trying to get some value, e.g. userId, I am using dynamic path according to XML type:

```
    SELECT 
    @type1 = @xml.exist('(/CreditInquiryResponse/creditReport/processingResult)'),
    @type2 = @xml.exist('(/BIKReportResult/ReportObject/processingResult)')
```

Then I am constructing the path and here is my problem. When it is constructed from two parts and then separated directly in xml.value by slash character then it works and I am getting userId value.

```
if(@type1 = 1)
begin
    SET @reportPathFirstPart = 'CreditInquiryResponse'
    SET @reportPathSecondPart = 'creditReport'
end

if(@type2 = 1)
begin
    SET @reportPathFirstPart = 'BIKReportResult'
    SET @reportPathSecondPart = 'ReportObject'
end

SELECT @userId = @xml.value('(/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@reportPathFirstPart")]/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@reportPathSecondPart")]/reportHeader/userId)[1]','varchar(max)')
```

But when I am trying to concatenate it as one variable then it does not work and I am getting NULL as userId value.

```
SET @reportPath = @reportPathFirstPart + '/' + @reportPathSecondPart

SELECT @userId = @xml.value('(/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@reportPath")]/reportHeader/userId)[1]','varchar(max)')
```

Has anyone an idea why is that? Or maybe it is a better way to get dynamic path like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this correctly, you are looking for nodes within `<reportHeader>`, but this node is not situated in the same nesting structure? You can use a *deep search* by starting your `Xpath` with a doubled slash:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(//reportHeader/userId/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)');
```

**read it as:** Find a `<reportHeader>` in any place

If you know, that there are two levels with different names, you might do this:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/*/*/reportHeader/userId/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')
```

**read it as:** Open the root node and any node below and find a `<reportHeader>` within

Another approach is to search for any node where there is a sub-node `reportHeader`. You can pick the infos within `reportHeader`, or any other info below this node:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(//*[reportHeader]/reportHeader/userId/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')
```

**read it as:** Find any node within the XML which has a sub-node `<reportHeader>`. Proceed from there.

Comment: one more time thank's a lot - as always I can teach something new from you. XPath deep search is the key. I will use second approach because of nodes with same names in other part of XML (like Client, Address etc) but two other ways may be an inspiration for someone else. Thank you!